# md5sum validation for a file

Tags: bash, ubuntu-12.04, ubuntu-13.10

I have two files `hello.txt` and `hello.txt.md5`

MD5 output is in the below format

```
cat hello.txt.md5 
b1946ac92492d2347c6235b4d2611184
```

I wrote a simple script to validate md5sum.

```
csum=$(cat hello.txt.md5)
echo "$csum hello.txt" | md5sum -c
```

This script works fine with `Ubuntu 13.10` but it throws below error in `Ubuntu 12.04`.

> md5sum: standard input: no properly formatted MD5 checksum lines found

Can anyone show me how to do this in Ubuntu12.04.

Comment: What are the versions of `md5sum`? I bet the file format has changed

Comment: The input of `md5sum -c` is supposed to be like the output. So what does `md5sum hello.txt` output look like on 12.04?

Answer (score 4):

At least on my md5sum files generated have *two* spaces between checksum and file name. Tested your script and it didn't work, added space between $csum and hello.txt and it did.

Comment: Yes it got to work now for me, u r right it should be with two spaces if it for Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 4):

The cause is likely to be some change between the `md5sum` versions.

Doing `md5sum <file1> <file2>` with both versions should give you an example of what format each version expects.

Specifically, the [`md5sum` man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/md5sum) says:

> The default mode is to print a line with checksum, a character indicating type ('*' for binary, ' ' for text), and name for each FILE.

So, for checking in text mode, *two* spaces shall normally be present (indeed, checking with `md5sum -t t.txt` confirms this). I guess the new version has lifted this requirement.

Indeed, [here's a GNU coreutils commit](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/commit/src/md5sum.c?id=7da844cc86e1209acbe820771b0e9a35fd89da3b) titled *"md5sum: handle BSD reversed format checksums"*, dated 2011-09-16. It makes `md5sum` guess between the two formats.
The commit was [released in `coreutils 8.14`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/NEWS?id=7b68a431111ceb443f9add5cb929148956e48cae) while Ubuntu 12.04 [uses `8.13`](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/+source/coreutils).